# How to get daily open inventory with a dynamic end date without storing results in an aggregate table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to see if there is a way to get the total daily inventory for open items in the past few months. Basically, each record has a start date and an end date. The start date is always the same. The end date will be null until it has been processed. Once processed, it is updated with a process date. Getting one day is fine, but I need to get the total volume, everyday, for a the last few months.

My current method of doing this is putting the results in an aggregate table. I can run the results one time through a while loop, then each day run whatever open volume there is from a stored procedure. This method works, but seems messy.

```
DECLARE @D AS DATE = '04/01/2019'
WHILE @D <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO DBO.OPEN_INVENTORY
SELECT
@D OPEN_DATE
,COUNT(1) OPEN_VOLUME
FROM
DBO.INVENTORY_RECORDS
WHERE
@D BETWEEN START_DATE AND ISNULL(END_DATE,'12/31/2199')
SET @D = DATEADD(D,+1,@D)
END
```

I would like to reproduce these results without having to store the volumes into an aggregate table. Is there a way to accomplish this in a single select?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best way would be to use what's known as a "Tally Table". They are extremely quick are building large sets of sequential data, and unlike a `WHILE`, `CURSOR` or rCTE, aren't recursive.

This is a big of a stab in the dark, as I have no sample data, but I *think* this is what you're after.

```
DECLARE @D AS DATE = '20190104';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1000 rows should be enough?
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @D) AS CalendarDate
    FROM Tally T
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @D) <= GETDATE())
SELECT D.CalendarDate,
       COUNT(IR.YourIDColumn) AS OPEN_VOLUMNE
FROM Dates D
     LEFT JOIN DBO.INVENTORY_RECORDS IR ON D.Date >= IR.START_DATE
                                       AND (D.Date <= IR.END_DATE OR IR.END_DATE IS NULL)
GROUP BY D.CalendarDate;
```

If not, try to troubleshoot it yourself, and then supply sample and expected results if not.